# drawing arrows in mql4 across specific candles in history

Tags: mql4, forex

I need create a code to loop across the history in a chart, i need put an arrow on every candlestick on time GMT00 like the image, thanks for the help and suggestions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For now i solve it using this code in OnInit() function

for(int i=0;i<Bars;i++)
{

```
   if(TimeHour(Time[i]) == 0)
  {
  //        
     ObjectCreate(i, OBJ_ARROW, 0, Time[i], High[i]+100*Point); //draw an up arrow
     ObjectSet(i, OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_SOLID);
     ObjectSet(i, OBJPROP_ARROWCODE, SYMBOL_ARROWDOWN);
     ObjectSet(i, OBJPROP_COLOR, Yellow);  
  }      
   
   
   
 }
```

[image]